# Sending email in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, xcode4.2

I am getting this warning

```
MessageUI.framework/MessageUI, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

What does it say ?

I have added the Message Framework by drag and dropping to my resources folder (I also selected the tick where it says copy the files or something). Is this the correct way to add a framework ? I tired R-clicking the resource folder, but I couldn't find any menu option that says add framework or anything similar. (I am using `xcode 4.2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually add `MessageUI` framework in your project.

To do that follow this step:

1) Click on your **main project --> Go to Target ---> Select Build Phases --> Select Link Binary With Libraries.**

[image]

2)  Click on **+** sign and add framework named `MessageUI.framework`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you should add the framework through target setting, under build phases, under link binary with libraries, add messageUI.framework there, DO NOT drag and drop and COPY into the resource folder.